# Add two functions in a table with the same variables

Tags: equation-solving, programming, parametric-functions, procedural-programming

How can I print the values of the function expere in the table of the function exper ... Note that I use this code

```
exp := Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] + 
  Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 4]

exper := Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] + 
  Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 4]

variables = exp // Variables // Sort;

Module[{expValue, experValue, varValues}, 
 With[{nbrOfResults = 10}, 
    Table[Catch[
       Do[If[0 <= (experValue = 
            Round[exper /. 
              Thread[variables -> (varValues = 
                  Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[variables]], .1])], 
             0.01]) < 1, 
         Throw[{NumberForm[#, {3, 1}] & /@ varValues, 
            NumberForm[experValue, {4, 2}]} // Flatten]], 
        10000]], {nbrOfResults}] // SortBy[#, Last] &] // 
   Prepend[#, {variables, "exp", "exper"} // Flatten] & // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &]
```

This program compensates the values of the variables of a function and gives the result of the function in the shape of a table ... A column should be added to a second function with the same variables as in the image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them along with the other `NumberForm`s and adjust the sort criterion

```
Module[{expValue, experValue, varValues}, 
 With[{nbrOfResults = 10}, 
    Table[Catch[
       Do[If[0 <= (experValue = 
            Round[exper /. 
              Thread[variables -> (varValues = 
                  Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[variables]], .1])], 
             0.01]) < 1, 
         Throw[{NumberForm[#, {3, 1}] & /@ varValues, 
            NumberForm[experValue, {4, 2}], 
  NumberForm[exper /. Thread[variables -> varValues], {4, 2}]} // Flatten]],
        10000]], {nbrOfResults}] // SortBy[#, #[[-2]] &] &] // 
   Prepend[#, {variables, "exp", "exper"} // Flatten] & // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &]
```

Comment: what mean SortBy[#, #[[-2]] &] &] When the equations are replaced by more variables it is so wrong    Part::partd: Part specification Null[[-2]] is longer than depth of object.

Comment: But the code does not produce the correct results

Comment: @Emadkareem The code below "I used this answer" is almost the same as what I wrote, but you replaced `experValue`by `expValue` in the `If` condition, so experValue remains a symbol. I don't see how you encountered `Null[[-2]]` though

Comment: The problem has been resolved in your answer. You have repeated the function experValue and have not noticed it